# How can I implement a Class that changes its "last_edited" variable every time its attribute is changed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, I have a class:

```
import datetime

class Obj:
    
    def __init__(self, attribute_1):
        self.attribute_1 = attribute_1
        self.last_edited = None
```

I want it to be able to do this:

```
# Creating object
obj1 = Obj("a") 
obj1.attribute_1 = "b"  # obj1.last_edited should have changed to datetime.datetime.now()
```

I'm not sure how to implement the changing of obj1's 'last_edited' attribute if I were to directly change obj1's 'attribute_1' (without any setters).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All Python objects have a builtin method called `__setattr__` that is called whenever a field in the class is changed.  This method by default updates a value in the class dictionary (stored internally to represent the state of a class instance).  You can override this behavior by defining a custom `__setattr__` method.  For your use case, the function might look like this:

```
class SomeObject:
    def __init__(self, attr):
        self.attr = attr

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        super().__setattr__("last_edited", time.time())
        super().__setattr__(name, value)
```

Notice that we need to use a `super` call to avoid recursion (use the `__setattr__` method of the base `object` class).

Comment: Note: Please read the current version of the answer.  I made a small mistake in the previous version.